# How to check out a specific tag with Egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Egit is a popular Eclipse plugin that integrates Eclipse with Git/GitHub.

With Git, if I want to work on a specific tag of a project, I clone that project and then run

```
git checkout tags/<tagName>
```

However, I don't see how I can do this with Egit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the project `Team` -> `Switch To` -> `Other...`. Expand `Tags`, select desired tag, click `Checkout` button.

Comment: You are welcome. Just a side note: egit is not very intuitive tool to use, plus since it uses jgit it misses some of git features. I recommend you to stick with console or install something like sourcetree if you want nice gui.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandr M (+1) - so then a quick question regarding using the console for all Git stuff: if I clone a git repo to, say, `/home/myuser/workspace/myapp`, then I would build an Eclipse project and point it at that directory. What happens to that directory when I run `git checkout tags/v2.3.4` (if that is a valid tag)? Would the whole project change to reflect the state it was in for the tag? Or do I need to clone to, say, `/home/myuser/workspace/myapp`, and then checkout to, say, `/home/myuser/workspace/myapp/v2.3.4`, and then point Eclipse to that (tag) directory?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, EGit recognizes changes in the branch made from the console. You do not need to refresh as with other Eclipse projects. You can tell it switched when the project shows the new branch name. (It can take a few seconds.)

Comment: @smeeb: It is the same as with external changes to some project file. Eclipse will automatically change files and branches/tags. Another side note: it is not recommended to keep git projects in eclipse workspace.